# How do I remove a previously "allowed" application profile from Ufw?

Tags: ufw

I've been messing around writing different application profiles for Ufw to get it to work properly, but I can't figure out how to completely and correctly remove an application profile that I previously added with `sudo ufw allow [application profile]`.

I've even tried uninstallning (`sudo apt purge ufw`) and reinstalling and this removes everything in `/etc/ufw` except the `applications.d` dir, so no settings could be lurking in `/etc/ufw`. I have also removed the actual profile file from the `applications.d` dir, but still every time I run:

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
```

I get

```
WARN: Skipping '[profile I removed]': field too long
```

However the firewall settings in the removed profile is deactivated as they should as of the output from `sudo ufw status verbose`.

Comment: `sudo apt purge ufw` deletes the `ufw` package from your system. Surely this was not your intent. `sudo apt install ufw`, then read `man ufw`, especially about `sudo ufw delete ...`.

Comment: Thanks for you comment! Sorry, I was unclear (edited now), I meant to explain that even a reinstall of Ufw, and checking that the `/etc/ufw` dir was emptied didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

You can delete application profiles in the same way you delete regular rules.

1. Get a list of the current rules:

   ```bsh
   $ ufw status numbered
   Status: active

       To                         Action      From
       --                         ------      ----
   [1] OpenSSH                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
   [2] mosh                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
   ```
2. Delete the rule by using the corresponding ID inside `[]`

   ```
   $ ufw delete 2
   Deleting:
    allow 'mosh'
   Proceed with operation (y|n)?
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this syntax:

```
sudo ufw delete <action> <application>
```

For instance,

```
sudo ufw delete allow openssh
```